# Why do I get "Syntax error near '$rocks['" in this Perl code?

Tags: perl, arrays

When I run this program on ActivePerl 5.8 on Windows XP, I get a syntax error:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe

use strict; # enabled
use warnings;


(my $rocks[0], my $rocks[1]) = qw/Hello World/; # Syntax error near '$rocks['

my $rocks[2] = 'Tom'; # Syntax error near '$rocks['
my $rocks[3] = 'Cat'; # Syntax error near '$rocks['

print $rocks[0];
print $rocks[1];
print $rocks[2];
print $rocks[3];
```

When I used (`@`) before the name of the array `rocks`, it worked well. 
How do I fix the error above when I used `$`?  Thank you.

```
my @rocks = qw{Hello World Tom Cat}; # worked well.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you prefer initializing `@rocks` in separate statements rather than all at once with `qw//`?

Comment: This looks close to one of the examples in Intermediate Perl. We show the single element access first, then build up to initializing the array all at once.

Comment: Learning Perl, not Intermediate Perl.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `my` again and again to declare `$rocks[0]`, `$rocks[1]` etc. 
Declare the array once (`@rocks`) and use it.

The corrected code is something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
my @rocks; ## declare the array here

($rocks[0], $rocks[1]) = qw/Hello World/; 
$rocks[2] = 'Tom'; 
$rocks[3] = 'Cat';
```

Comment: Niggle:  Please correct the references to `$rock[0]` and `$rock[1]` to refer to the correct variable.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) operator:

```
my @rocks;

push @rocks, qw/ Hello World /;
push @rocks, "Tom";
push @rocks, "Cat";
```

Avoiding explicit and redundant array indices helps future-proof your code. For example, if you find you need to change your initialization, you can't botch an array index that isn't there.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to declare `my @rocks` and then not use `my` any more when referring to `$rocks[xxx]`.

If you don't know how many elements are going to be in there, you can use `push` to add new elements into the (initially 0-sized) array.

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring `@rocks` several times. Try something like this instead:

```
my @rocks;

$rocks[0] = 'Tom';
$rocks[1] = 'Cat';
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can first declare the array at the top as:

```
my @rocks;
```

And remove my declaration from all other places.

Your code becomes:

```
#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe
# ActivePerl 5.8 based
use strict; # enabled
use warnings;

my @rocks;

($rocks[0], $rocks[1]) = qw/Hello World/; # Syntax error near '$rocks['

$rocks[2] = 'Tom'; # Syntax error near '$rocks['
$rocks[3] = 'Cat'; # Syntax error near '$rocks['

print $rocks[0];
print $rocks[1];
print $rocks[2];
print $rocks[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put it straight into `@rocks`?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @rocks = qw'Hello World';

my $rocks[2] = 'Tom';
my $rocks[3] = 'Cat';

print $rocks[0];
print $rocks[1];
print $rocks[2];
print $rocks[3];
```